# Trying to create custom error alerts

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

I tried creating my own custom error page with a twist. (Nothing original) Basically when the custom error page gets hit it will take the url of the error and the username of the person is logged in and sends me a short smtp e-mail. It actually is working great but it am getting these e-mails at crazy hours on pages that I test and i see nothing wrong with. I want to try and grab some information on why this custom error page was called so I can try and fix the problem.

Would anyone have any recommendations so I can enhance this page to give me more information.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        string DATETIME = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        string UserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();

        string fileName = Server.MapPath("_TextFiles/error.txt");
        string mailBody = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##url##", url);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##DATETIME##", DATETIME);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##UserName##", UserName);

        MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
        myMessage.Subject = "Response from ";
        myMessage.Body = mailBody;

        myMessage.From = new MailAddress("*******n.com", "******");
        myMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("*********.com", "******"));

        SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        mySmtpClient.Send(myMessage);

    }
```

The Text file so thee is no confusion.

```
Hello,

Response from Error.aspx


An error occured on page ##url##

at ##DATETIME##


Username: ##UserName##
```

Comment: why not add the error message as well?    then you'll know what is tripping it at least.

Comment: That is what i am trying to do but i probably explained it poorly.

Comment: how are you passing the message to your email process?

Comment: Not sure if i am understanding you correctly,  but the variables I declare on top replace the ##values## that are in a text file. It uses that text file as the body of the e-mail and will send a e-mail using googles smtp server that i declared in my web.config file.

Comment: so the text file doesn't have the info you need or it isn't getting carried over to the email?     how are you building the text file?

Comment: its just a template for the body of the e-mail. Nothing to do with anything else.

Comment: i want to grab the error that caused the user to be directed to the custom error page.

Comment: what is the code for error.aspx?   are you certain the exception message is making it to this page?

Comment: What is the traget framework of your web app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same basic setup with my sites, but you need to change your method a bit.  If you send your email from the error page, the exception is no longer available.  Here is what I do...

I extend the `System.Web.UI.Page` class and override the `OnError` method with the following:

```
protected override void OnError(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnError(e);

    System.Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    Log.LogError("Error in Supr.CMS.Types.SuprPage", ex, Log.LogLevel.HandledExceptionFatal);
}
```

I now use this as my base class for all pages and I am notified on all errors with complete details.  I include the exception message and stack trace and some user info (including IP address and UserAgent), the cookie collection, session collection, forms collection and cache collection so I know as best as possible the state of the site when the user encountered the error (a little too much to post here).

Another note...  A lot of the errors are generated by bots and having info like the IP and UserAgent allow me to break that down and enhance my request blocking.